# NanoFramework Device Explorer would not open

Tags: c#, .net, nanoframework

I was able to use nanoframework normally but somehow the DeviceExplorer no longer opens now.

I checked the ActivityLog.xml and it shows the following error:

```
819 ERROR SetSite failed for package [Visual Studio 2019 extension for nanoFramework. Enables creating C# Solutions to be deployed to a target board and provides debugging tools.]Source: 'nanoFramework.Tools.VS2019.Extension' Description: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading, Version=16.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading, Version=16.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. File name: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading, Version=16.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'at nanoFramework.Tools.VisualStudio.Extension.NanoFrameworkPackage.<InitializeAsync>d__65.MoveNext()at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)at nanoFramework.Tools.VisualStudio.Extension.NanoFrameworkPackage.InitializeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, IProgress`1 progress)at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.AsyncPackage.<>c__DisplayClass20_0.<<Microsoft-VisualStudio-Shell-Interop-IAsyncLoadablePackageInitialize-Initialize>b__1>d.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.RethrowException(AggregateException e)at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.InternalGetResult(Boolean ignoreUIThreadCheck)at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.GetResult() WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].  {046B40EB-1DE1-4D08-AF61-FDB7592B9BBD} 80070002 VisualStudio 2021/03/21 07:18:45.265 
820 ERROR End package load [Visual Studio 2019 extension for nanoFramework. Enables creating C# Solutions to be deployed to a target board and provides debugging tools.] {046B40EB-1DE1-4D08-AF61-FDB7592B9BBD} 80070002 VisualStudio 2021/03/21 07:18:45.270
```

I want to highlight that my Visual Studio nanoframework extension is set to update automatically and it sounds like it recently got updated to 2019.5.0.34

I am using Visual Studio Profession 2019 16.8.3

Disabling/Enabling the extension, restarting the visual studio did not help.

Any clue what could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 3):

You should update Visual Studio to 16.9 or higher.

Comment: Upgrading to Visual studio 16.9, upgrading firmware to latest version, upgrading all nuget packages to latest version, removing all unused nuget packages resolved the issue. To avoid the entire cycle in midst, I would keep the automatic update of extension off for future :)

Comment: If I've answered your question satisfactorily please mark the answer as accepted :)